# JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes

Tags: python, json, decode

```
import json as js
CONFIG_FILE_NAME = "Config.json"
FILE = open(CONFIG_FILE_NAME,'r')
CONFIG_FILE = [js.loads(CONTENT) for CONTENT in FILE]
```

This is my script i want to extract data from this Config.json file

```
 {
 "Files": {
 "Emails": {
 "FileName": "Emails.txt",
 "Location": "PasteHereLocation"
 },
 "Body": {
 "FileName": "Message.txt",
 "Location": "PasteHereLocation"
 },
 "Servers": {
 "FileName": "Servers.json",
 "Location": "PasteHereLocation"
 }
 }
}
```

But it gives this error. As i already tried different things like **1) json as raw string putting r' json content'** **2) Changing decode methods or 3) changing .json to .txt**. But still same error.

```
File "D:\Softwares\Technical\Anaconda\lib\json\decoder.py", line 353, in raw_decode
obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)

JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes
```

Kindly Review this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import json as js
CONFIG_FILE_NAME = "Config.json"
FILE = open(CONFIG_FILE_NAME,'r')
js.load(FILE)  # or use js.loads(FILE.read())
```

omit the line

```
CONFIG_FILE = [js.loads(CONTENT) for CONTENT in FILE]
```

**this is what's happening:** 
your file contains valid JSON but when you read your file *line by line* using `[[js.loads(CONTENT) for CONTENT in FILE]]` then variable `CONTENT` do not hold valid JSON anymore, they are just incomplete or invalid JSON line and then you try to load it into `json` module so that's what it is giving you an error.

Comment: You Save my day.. Thanks.. As i mentioned i have applied all possible ways but did not pay attention to this.. It worked..